# Passing variant data to Snowflake

Tags: python, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I have written a stored procedure in Snowflake. I am calling it from a python lambda function and I have already verified that I am passing valid json. I can't figure out how to use the data I passed to the stored procedure in my insert.

The part with "values(${variant_data}" in the insert is what is giving me trouble.

I read this [how to pass variant data into snowflake table using snowflake stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68625389/how-to-pass-variant-data-into-snowflake-table-using-snowflake-stored-procedure), which said that what I needed to do isn't completely supported in Snowflake. Apparently, I would need to convert the "variant_data" to string and then back to variant to use the data in my insert but the example wasn't clear to me.

This is my stored procedure.

```
create or replace procedure  MY_STORED_PROCEDURE("variant_data" variant)
    returns string
    language javascript
    strict
    execute as owner
    as
    $$
    var variant_data=variant_data;
    var sql_command = `
    insert into MY_TABLE(MY_VARIANT_DATA) values(${variant_data})
    `
    $$;
```

If someone could explain how to use variant data in my insert, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well first steps lets check our base SQL is in a acceptable form:

```
create table MY_TABLE(MY_VARIANT_DATA variant);
```

```
insert into my_table(my_variant_data) values 
    (parse_json('{"key1":"value1","key2":1234}'));
```

> Invalid expression [PARSE_JSON('{"key1":"value1","key2":1234}')] in VALUES clause

ok, so lets make that a SELECT and PARSE_JSON:

```
insert into my_table(my_variant_data) select 
    (parse_json('{"key1":"value1","key2":1234}'));
```

| number of rows inserted |
| --- |
| 1 |

ok so that works for a single value (of which is really not how you should load data into snowflake, I mean if you have 1 piece of data per hour sure, its' fine but if you doing this often, your tables will be very fragmented)..

so lets try casting to `::VARIANT`

```
insert into my_table(my_variant_data) values 
   ('{"key1":"value1","key2":1234}'::variant);
```

> Invalid expression [CAST('{"key1":"value1","key2":1234}' AS VARIANT)] in VALUES clause

ok, so a multi-insert via a SELEC FROM VALUES:

```
insert into my_table(my_variant_data) 
    select parse_json(column1) 
    from values
        ('{"key1":"value1","key2":1234}'),
        ('{"key1":"value2","key2":1235}');
```

| number of rows inserted |
| --- |
| 2 |

Ok, so we now have a couple of patterns of valid INSERT sql..

lets recreate the procedure using that, this will look like "cheating" as it's a full working code, but it took me way to long to get things working. Basically I didn't read Felipe's answer too deeply, anyways, in the end I settle for string concatenation, which is a security risk, so I really wouldn't do it this way:

```
create or replace procedure MY_STORED_PROCEDURE("variant_as_string" text)
    returns string
    language javascript
    strict
    execute as owner
    as
    $$
    var sql_command = "insert into my_table(my_variant_data) select (parse_json('"+ variant_as_string +"'));";
    var sql = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sql_command});
    var resultSet = sql.execute();
    return sql_command;
    $$;
```

which works! although should maybe not be used..

```
-- lets the prior inserts
truncate table MY_TABLE;

-- do new  insert
call MY_STORED_PROCEDURE('{"key1":"value4","key2":1238}');

-- look at the results
select * from my_table;
```

| MY_VARIANT_DATA |
| --- |
| { "key1": "value4", "key2": 1238 } |

but that also changed the input type from variant to test...

by the way how I debugged this stuff was comment bit out like so:

```
create or replace procedure MY_STORED_PROCEDURE("variant_data" variant)
    returns string
    language javascript
    strict
    execute as owner
    as
    $$
    var sql_command = "insert into my_table(my_variant_data) select (parse_json('"+ JSON.stringify(variant_data) +"'));";
    //var sql = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sql_command});
    //var resultSet = sql.execute();
    return sql_command;
    $$;
```

and read the SQL to see it made me happy, anyway the with those two line uncommented out, works for variant data:

```
call MY_STORED_PROCEDURE(parse_json('{"key1":"value12","key2":12345}'));
```

```
select * from my_table;
```

| MY_VARIANT_DATA |
| --- |
| { "key1": "value4", "key2": 1238 } |
| { "key1": "value12", "key2": 12345 } |

So there you have it, two ways to inject a single row in a table. Both which possible should be avoid for SQL injection reasons, a to do that correctly, you should use Felipe's answer on that other question.

```
create or replace procedure MY_STORED_PROCEDURE("variant_data" variant)
    returns string
    language javascript
    strict
    execute as owner
    as
    $$
    var sql_command = "insert into my_table(my_variant_data) select (parse_json(:1));";
    var sql = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sql_command, binds:[JSON.stringify(variant_data)]});
    var resultSet = sql.execute();
    return sql_command;
    $$;
```

```
call MY_STORED_PROCEDURE(parse_json('{"key1":"value123","key2":123456}'));
```

which gives:

| MY_VARIANT_DATA |
| --- |
| { "key1": "value4", "key2": 1238 } |
| { "key1": "value12", "key2": 12345 } |
| { "key1": "value123", "key2": 123456 } |

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will play around with this tomorrow. Basically, my use case is my previous question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71521540/looping-through-array-of-objects-in-json-file-downloaded-from-s3?noredirect=1#comment126411657_71521540. I am calling my stored procedure for each iteration of my loop. I'm not sure if this is the best approach. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I got it working using the last method. Thanks for the comprehensive explanation. It was extremely helpful.